# How can I combine numeric values of similar strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of licenses and associated license counts, for example:

```
1 Third Party SIP Device Seat   
1 Third Party SIP Device Seat   
1 Third Party SIP Device Seat   
3 Station   
3 Station   
3 Station   
20 Station
```

The lists are never in the same order and I simply need to add the totals for each license type so in the example I would want the return:

```
3 Third Party SIP Device Seat
29 Station
```

The data is being entered into unsaved notepad and later moved into a database. Using excel isn't applicable as it's spaces between the numbers and names, not tabs.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Well, you can tell Excel to split your data by space or any other delimeter of your choosing

Comment: "_What would be the easiest way to accomplish this task?_" Using python to automate all this sounds like an easy way to accomplish the task.

Comment: You can use the python package pandas. As @Will stated most tools including pandas and excel can use any delimiter to read a text file.

Comment: If I did space delimited it would mess up the names and I'd be left with a bunch of unnecessary tabs in the names that I would have to remove afterwards

Comment: @TrebledJ That is the goal, I just don't know how to. Which library would I use?

Comment: Read the file lines, split each one on the index of the first space, parse the number as an int, and build a dictionary of licence to total count. Go!

Comment: itertools has a groupby. don't really need pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a super ugly solution:

```
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

lines = [       # replace with e.g: with open('input.txt', 'r') as f: lines = f.readlines()
  "1 Third Party SIP Device Seat",   
  "1 Third Party SIP Device Seat",  
  "1 Third Party SIP Device Seat", 
  "3 Station",
  "3 Station",  
  "3 Station",  
  "20 Station"
]

def f(acc, x):
  acc[" ".join(x.split(" ")[1:])] += int(x.split(" ")[0]) # first element is the count, everything after we use as "key"
  return acc

r = dict(reduce(f, lines, defaultdict(int)))

print(r)
# {'Third Party SIP Device Seat': 3, 'Station': 29}

# to write to file:
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:  
  for k, v in r.items():
    f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k))
```

Comment: I like the use defaultdict and reduce. clever

Comment: @Jeppe So this is perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I added a few more steps to the data processing to make it work, mainly adding the first tab for each line and the quotation marks and comma at the end and everything works like a charm.

With that said, would it be possible to extract the data into a new word file? So I could save the data for each company in their own word document automatically with a file name that I set within the code each time? Also, instead of separating the entries by , can it be by a new line instead?

I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: I really just need to be able to save into a word document, from there I can just find and replace each , with a new line.

Comment: @KevinBurris I added the code to write the contents to file. You can alter delimiter, etc. in the string being built in the line `f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k))`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I adjusted the last line as so: f.write(str(v) + " " + str(k) + "\n") and now I am getting everything that I needed! Now that I've got my project working, I can fully automate the process and spend some time studying how this code works and the code from the other answers. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me as I delve further into Python!

Comment: @KevinBurris No problem, feel free to ask otherwise. The `f(acc, x)` function can probably be cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You want a groupby. Fortunately itertools has one

```
from itertools import groupby 

text = """1 Third Party SIP Device Seat    
1 Third Party SIP Device Seat    
1 Third Party SIP Device Seat    
3 Station    
3 Station    
3 Station    
0 Station""" 

# clean stuff up and split on first space
lines = [line.strip().split(" ", 1) for line in text.split("\n")]

# groupby
result = []
for k, g in groupby(lines, lambda x: x[1]): 
    total = 0 
    for i in g: 
        total += int(i[0]) 
    result.append([k, total])  
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution with data in a "saved notepad file" named `licences.txt`:

```
from collections import Counter
counter=Counter()
with open ('licences.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        count,*words = line.split()
        counter[" ".join(words)] += int(count)

with open('grouped_licences.txt','w') as f:
    for licence,total in counter.items():
        f.write(str(total) + " " + licence + "\n")
```

Then result is in file `grouped_licences.txt`:

```
    3 Third Party SIP Device Seat 
    29 Station
```

---

Another solution with `pandas` :

```
df=pandas.read_csv('licences.txt', sep=" ",header=None).fillna("")        
df["licence"]=df.iloc[:,1:].apply(" ".join,axis=1)        
print(df.groupby("licence")[0].sum())
```

For :

```
licence
Station                           29
Third Party SIP Device Seat        3
```